# setting ftp service via web with python

Tags: python, linux, ftp

sorry if my english bad...

anyone can tell me how to setting ftp service via web using python...
i want my site can control the ftp service like sinology diskstation..
like enable/disable ftp service, control how many connection, add or remove user, etc.
i use linux and python+django
or just give me where to find the article..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: http://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/

Filezilla can be controlled by command lines.  The users and other parameters can be edited in the Server XML file.